# Migrating Kubuntu bootable USB to SSD

Tags: usb, hard-drive, kubuntu, ssd

I'm currently running Kubuntu 16.04 on a bootable USB.

My HDD and SSD aren't usable. They're in "root/dev/disk/by-id/" as unknown files. I can find the HDD as "sda" in "root/dev", but it's a hidden file and its file type is block device.

How do I mount my HDD and SSD so I can use them as storage? I want to move my OS to the SSD.

Comment: if you solved an issue yourself post that as an answer below instead of editing the question. also asking multiple questions per post is not a good idea. right now it's not clear from your post what issue needs an answer and what is solved.

Comment: @root thanks, new here; will upload second issue as another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steam isn't displaying after running [Kubuntu]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799533/steam-isnt-displaying-after-running-kubuntu?noredirect=1#comment1205606_799533) 
@Nick Weinberg solved the OS migrating problem

(edited out of original post)

Sound solution: Plugged earphones into monitor to see if youtube video sound would output (didn't work) but upon removing the headphones the sound came out of the monitor speakers

Stuttering start menu and youtube videos: go to start menu and type "monitor" to bring up Display Configuration, click Advanced Settings and set it to 60hz instead of auto and apply the settings. fixed