# Steam isn't displaying after running [Kubuntu]

Tags: kubuntu, wine, steam, winetricks, konsole

- Steam won't run properly, it just shows up at the bottom panel for a few seconds then disappears and there's not even an icon next to the tab. No window comes up.

I have WINE & winetricks installed.

How do I get Steam to run properly? I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: I tried the answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts but because I'm booting from a usb and thats the only storage space kubuntu notices,  as soon as I run steam, it doesn't have enough space for an update. More on that here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/799463/migrating-usb-boot-to-ssd-kubuntu/799522#799522

Comment: Then that's a completely different problem :) And  the solution is to either install Ubuntu to your hard drive or upgrade your computer's RAM.

Comment: My ram is fine (4x2 sticks of 1866mhz detected) but I have no clue how to move Kubuntu to my hard drive if its not detected :(

Comment: Have you tried running the Ubuntu installer to see if it detects your SSD?

Comment: No idea how to. Sorry, I'm new to Linux.

Comment: There should be an icon on the desktop and in the applications menu to "Install Ubuntu"

Comment: Awesome, they're both there. :D What is the difference between installing guided all disk or all disk and lvm? Or should I do manual? I want to be able to use my hard drive for storage, not just booting.

Comment: As long as you don't have any data you'll miss on the drive (because the installer will delete it all!!!), just choose "use entire disk" and you'll be fine; you'll be able to use any free space for storage for your files.

Comment: They're both completely new! Thank you so much for your help. :D I'm about to save it to my sdd. Wish I could give you credit for the answer! I'll link this thread to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/799463/migrating-usb-boot-to-ssd-kubuntu/799522#799522

Comment: Of course, it did not work. :( It crashes everytime when I reach the TimeZone page. Except this time the ssd isn't empty,  it says it has sda5 (linux-swap) in it.
I go into the terminal and type "ubuntu-bug ubiquity" and it brings up a window saying "Your /var partition has less than 29.028352 MB of free space[...]" which is worrying because the first time I tried to run the installer it said the same error but I had about 49 MB of free space.

Comment: I think that's happening because the Live USB stores all your files (incliding Steam, etc) in RAM, and your computer is running out of space in RAM! Try rebooting, and boot into the Ubuntu USB stick again using the "Try Ubuntu" option. Then click the "Install Ubuntu" icon on your desktop, and do the installation. Try not to install Steam or run lots of programs or anything *until after Ubuntu is installed* and you've booted into your newly-installed system on your SSD.

Comment: I never got a "Try Ubuntu" option, it goes straight to running.
Is there a way to get back the space taken in RAM?
I'm going to reboot now and re-try the installation.

Comment: Rebooting  should reset everything and free up RAM. Hopefully the installation will go better this time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steam doesn't start after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761176/steam-doesnt-start-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04)

This sorta fixed it.. I have to input `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam` whenever I want to run Linux Steam and wait for it to update (along with keycode verification) each time which is quite annoying.. Will post another question about this.

More on that here: [(steamwebhelper.exe error) Nothing but library [Windows Steam using Wine] - Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799851/nothing-but-library-windows-steam-using-wine-kubuntu) (in the comments)
Decided to just use the Windows version of Steam to play and the Linux version whenever I want to purchase a game, which is a chore but there doesn't seem to be any solution to this constant update issue yet...