# Kubuntu Installer keeps crashing

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu, ssd, crash

It crashes everytime I reach the TimeZone page. The first time I tried to run it, the ssd was empty, the 3rd or 2nd time it says it has sda5 (linux-swap) in it. I go into the terminal and type "`ubuntu-bug ubiquity`" and it brings up a window saying "Your /var partition has less than 29.028352 MB of free space[...]" which is worrying because the first time I tried to run the installer it said the same error but I had about 49 MB of free space.

I'm currently booting from a live USB.
What must I do to get this working and get back the space I lost?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting the "out of space" message because the Live USB stores all your files (including Steam and any other programs that you [installed previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799533/steam-isnt-displaying-after-running-kubuntu/799547#799547)) in RAM, and your computer is running out of space in RAM!

Try rebooting (which will reset everything and free up your RAM), and boot into the Ubuntu USB installer and start the installation process again. Try not to install Steam or run lots of programs or anything until *after Ubuntu is installed* and you've booted into your newly-installed system on your SSD.

Comment: Perfect! :D Thank you, re-booting fixed the issue!