# (steamwebhelper.exe error) Nothing but library [Windows Steam using Wine] - Kubuntu

Tags: windows, kubuntu, wine, steam

When I run the Windows version of Steam on Kubuntu, the only thing I can view and use is the library and the friend list, News is blank and all the other pages load forever.

How do I get the other pages such as profile and storepage to load? Thanks.

**EDIT: steamwebhelper.exe program error details:**

```
0x100aa6d9: int $3
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (91 modules)
PE    400000-  6d6000   Deferred        steamwebhelper
PE   2f70000- 3087000   Deferred        crashhandler
PE  10000000-130eb000   Export          libcef
ELF 7b800000-7ba63000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba63000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcf2000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcf2000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7d2d7000-7d2fe000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7d2e0000-7d2fe000   \               mpr
ELF 7d80f000-7d887000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7d820000-7d887000   \               wininet
ELF 7d907000-7d974000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d910000-7d974000   \               setupapi
ELF 7d9c7000-7dc03000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7d9e0000-7dc03000   \               shell32
ELF 7dc07000-7dc3f000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7dc10000-7dc3f000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7dc3f000-7dc46000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7dc6f000-7dc7c000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7dc7f000-7dc8a000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7dc8f000-7dca2000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7dca7000-7dcae000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7dcaf000-7dcb3000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7dcb7000-7dcdd000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7dcdf000-7de2a000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7de2f000-7de44000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7de47000-7de4b000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7de4f000-7de5b000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7de5f000-7de66000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7de67000-7de6b000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7de6f000-7defe000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7de80000-7defe000   \               winex11
ELF 7deff000-7df23000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7df10000-7df23000   \               imm32
ELF 7e027000-7e051000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e057000-7e0a0000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e0cf000-7e0fa000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7e0ff000-7e11a000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e11f000-7e1cf000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e1f7000-7e22f000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e200000-7e22f000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e22f000-7e258000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e240000-7e258000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e25f000-7e28e000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e270000-7e28e000   \               netapi32
ELF 7e28f000-7e2c0000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7e2a0000-7e2c0000   \               secur32
ELF 7e2c7000-7e2f1000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e2d0000-7e2f1000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e2f7000-7e3af000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e300000-7e3af000   \               winmm
ELF 7e3af000-7e40c000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  7e3c0000-7e40c000   \               oleacc
ELF 7e40f000-7e50a000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e420000-7e50a000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e50f000-7e527000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e510000-7e527000   \               wtsapi32
ELF 7e527000-7e53f000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  7e530000-7e53f000   \               userenv
ELF 7e53f000-7e66f000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e560000-7e66f000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e66f000-7e6ee000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e680000-7e6ee000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e6ef000-7e826000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e710000-7e826000   \               ole32
ELF 7e827000-7e89e000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e830000-7e89e000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e89f000-7e8b3000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e8a0000-7e8b3000   \               psapi
ELF 7e8b7000-7e8fb000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7e8c0000-7e8fb000   \               usp10
ELF 7e8ff000-7e974000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e910000-7e974000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e977000-7ea92000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e980000-7ea92000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ea97000-7ebe7000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eab0000-7ebe7000   \               user32
ELF 7ebe7000-7ebfa000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ebff000-7ec1a000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ec27000-7ec41000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7ec30000-7ec41000   \               version
ELF 7ef7f000-7efd4000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efdf000-7efec000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7efef000-7eff9000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f73e7000-f759d000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f759f000-f75a4000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f75a7000-f75c4000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF f75ef000-f77a6000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77a7000-f77cc000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77d4000-f77d5000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    00000016    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000014 winedevice.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001b    0
    0000001a    0
    00000015    0
0000001c plugplay.exe
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
    0000001d    0
00000023 explorer.exe
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
00000028 Steam.exe
    00000068    0
    0000005a    0
    0000005f    0
    00000039    0
    00000038    0
    00000018    0
    00000019    0
    0000005c    0
    00000067    0
    00000066    0
    00000065   15
    00000064    0
    00000063    0
    00000062    0
    00000061    0
    00000060    0
    0000005e    1
    0000005b    0
    00000059    0
    00000045    0
    00000033    0
    00000032    0
    00000031    0
    0000002c    0
    00000029    0
00000058 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\bin\steamwebhelper.exe
    0000008d    0
    00000036    0
    0000008f    0
    00000034    0
    00000030    0
    0000006b    0
    00000097    0
    00000096    0 <==
    00000095    0
    00000094    0
    00000093    0
    0000006a    0
    00000035    0
    00000090    0
    0000003f    0
    00000055    0
    0000005d    0
    00000047    0
    0000000b    0
    00000048    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.8
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-31-generic
```

currently downloading IE 11 to see if it'll work with Steam. Will post results as soon as I get them.

Comment: Why are you running Steam on Wine? Steam has a native Linux client.

Comment: because the Linux version of Steam only works everytime I put `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam` into the terminal and I have to wait for it to update every time and provide a keycode (from Steam) to verify my computer, and when I played a Linux-supported game, it had many bugs.

Comment: The first issue can be fixed permanently by editing your `~/.bashrc`. The second issue is caused by the security settings you picked and isn't related to Kubuntu nor Wine. As for the third issue, that's a valid concern but I am not confident playing it through Wine will help much. What game is that by the way?

Comment: No idea how to fix all that, still new to Linux. The third issue was resolved by playing through Wine. "Detective Grimoire"

Answer (score 3):

If you run the windows version of steam on wine, you also need to make sure all dependencies are available. For example: steam for windows uses a browser as backend for its store and community. Not sure if it is Internet Explorer, but give it a try please. And if that does not work, install firefox and/or google chrome for windows under the wine, as well.

**Edit**
For videos to play, you most probably also need the adobe flash player for the browser that is used by steam.

Comment: After I installed the Windows version of Firefox and tried to run it, I received the program error "program firefox.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close" further telling me that it could be caused by a problem in the program or a deficiency in Wine. Is it because I installed the 64-bit version? When I click on Show Details, the first line I see is "Unhandled exception: unimplemented function msvcr120.dll._set_FMA3_enable called in 64-bit code (0x000000007b84c5e7)." and then a really long 'Register dump'. I'm going to try to download the 32-bit version now to see if thatwork

Comment: The 32-bit version works! I'm going to re-boot to see if the Steam Client'll use it now :D

Comment: Didn't change anything, but I did receive an error from Wine saying "steamwebhelper.exe has a serious problem and needs to close", I'll post the Program Error Details as a question.

Comment: Just tried to run it with PlayonLinux and still no dice. I get only the library and the friend list working properly, the rest just load on & on..

[inspired by https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-13306.html ]

Comment: Still recieving steamwebhelper.exe error after Flash download for Windows Firefox.  However, I think I installed it incorrectly because after agreeing to the terms and pressing install, the progress bar loads up very fast to 100% then bring up an error window saying "File not found." is the file in an inaccessible area? Where should I put it so that the installation can be completed properly?

Comment: Trying to install IE 11 and can't http://askubuntu.com/questions/800291/windows-internet-explorer-through-wine

Comment: Discussions on the steam forums suggest it's some form of Chrome used as the browser. http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/38596747746461596

Comment: other discussions on the steam forums suggest this video tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn8iSkKO6zc
aside from that, I am really at a loss here, as I never tried to use steam with wine.

Comment: I use the same setup as @HelpMeee for the same reason of being able to play Steam games that don't have Linux versions.  It works very well for some (Bulletstorm) not so much for others (Bioshock).  I also have the browser problem.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I use is to install the Linux version of Steam.  The store works there, you can buy the Windows games, then start the Wine-Steam and play them.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/799547/569100 I have update issues with the Linux version of Steam, so I wanted to avoid it completely.

Comment: From looking at the other question, maybe try this (fixed it for me) 1)Delete SteamApps/common/Portal 2/bin/libstdc++.so.6 2)Run the Steam client 3) cd "SteamApps/common/Portal 2" 4)LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin ./portal2_linux -game portal2 -windowed  ***I only had the problem with portal 2 but you could try this procedure with games you are experiencing trouble with.,  After running it once this way I could start it from the normal library window