# Windows Internet Explorer through Wine

Tags: windows, wine, steam, browser

I've downloaded the install files for IE 11 hoping it would load pages on Windows Steam because I'm having steamwebhelper.exe issues (more on that here: [(steamwebhelper.exe error) Nothing but library [Windows Steam using Wine] - Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799851/steamwebhelper-exe-error-nothing-but-library-windows-steam-using-wine-kubu))

Now when I try to install IE, I get a window saying "Internet Explorer needs an update before installing" then it opens a tab  in Firefox of "Prerequisite updates for Internet Explorer 11" even though I've installed them all. How do I get the installer to recognize the updates I downloaded so it may use it during the install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, Internet Explorer 11 does not work well under WINE, and you would be extremely lucky to get it working well.

The only available entry for IE 11's WINE compatibility currently rates it as "Garbage": https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33811

And as you can see on the Wine website, no version of Internet Explorer above 7.0 has been reported to work well (they're all "Garbage"): https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=25

I wish you luck getting it to work, but I think it's a losing battle. If the Linux version of Steam would work for your needs, I'd recommend using that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CrossOver? It doesn't have IE 11 support though, but IE8 have 3 star which stated that this version have run with limited functionality.